# Find the $\inf, \sup, \min, \max$, the interior and the closure of the set $\{1/2, -2/3, 3/4, -4/5,\ldots\}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

> Find the $\inf, \sup, \min, \max$, the interior and the closure of the set $\{1/2, -2/3, 3/4, -4/5,\ldots\}$

So I am sure I found the right inf and sup that being $-1$ and $1$ and the min and max do not exist because sup and inf are not included in the set, but I'm not sure about how I should find the interior and the closure.
So any help would be accepted. I know the definitions but I'm not sure I can quite compute them.

Comment: Interior point is simple(check for every element of the set), and for closure, find all limit points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Tuddy09, if you add more context and further information, I will help you solve your exercise. Please, click [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), read carefully and do what it recommends.